# iterators implementation in STL containers

Tags: c++, c++17

This is the sample code I've written, just a simple version to test out an iterator implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct ArrayIterator {
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using reference = value_type&;
  using self = ArrayIterator;
  
  pointer ptr;
  
  ArrayIterator() : ptr{nullptr} {}
  ArrayIterator(pointer ptr) : ptr{ptr} {}
  
  reference operator*() {
    return *ptr;
  }
  
  bool operator==(self const& other) const {
    return ptr == other.ptr;
  }
  
  bool operator!=(self const& other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }
  
  self operator++() {
    ++ptr;
    return *this;
  }
  
  self operator++(int) {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++ptr;
    return copy;
  }
  
};

template <typename T, size_t size>
struct Array {
  T arr[size];
  
  using value_type = T;
  using iterator = ArrayIterator<Array<T, size>>;
  
  iterator begin() {
    return iterator(arr);
  }
  
  Array() : arr{1, 3, 4, 22, 3} {}
  
  iterator end() {
    return iterator(arr + size);
  }
};

int main() {
  using array = Array<int, 5>;
  array arr;
}
```

Assuming everything is public, and we only pass `int` as type parameter, and the array has the default constructor just to test range-based `for` loop. It works.

My question is, why can't we use inheritance? Something like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t size>
struct Array : ArrayIterator<Array<T, size>> {}
```

If used, I get the following error (compiler is clang 11):

```
first.cpp:46:34: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'Array<int, 5>'
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
first.cpp:82:16: note: in instantiation of template class 'ArrayIterator<Array<int, 5>>' requested here
struct Array : ArrayIterator<Array<T, size>> {
               ^
first.cpp:101:9: note: in instantiation of template class 'Array<int, 5>' requested here
  array arr;
        ^
1 error generated
```

I can’t understand what's going on.

Comment: please always add the language tag. It helps your question to be seen by people following the tag and enabled syntax highlighting for code.

Comment: First, do you understand what the error message is?

Comment: Yes @user202729. no type found in T

Comment: Wait, why do you want to inherit the `Array` from `ArrayIterator`? An array is not an iterator.

Comment: If you want the array to be able to be used as an iterator, just write a conversion operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use inheritance like you want because the code will have a catch-22 if you try. `ArrayIterator` will try to define its `value_type` as an alias of the array’s `value_type` before the latter has been defined yet. That is why you are getting the compiler error.

Your iterator has no need to access the `Array` class itself, so there is no point in passing the `Array` class type to the iterator’s template parameter. Just pass the array’s `value_type` instead of `Array` itself, and change the iterator’s `value_type` to be just `T` instead of `typename T::value_type`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct ArrayIterator {
  using value_type = T;
  using pointer = value_type*;
  using reference = value_type&;
  using self = ArrayIterator;
  
  pointer ptr;
  
  ArrayIterator() : ptr{nullptr} {}
  ArrayIterator(pointer ptr) : ptr{ptr} {}
  
  reference operator*() {
    return *ptr;
  }
  
  bool operator==(self const& other) const {
    return ptr == other.ptr;
  }
  
  bool operator!=(self const& other) const {
    return ptr != other.ptr;
  }
  
  self& operator++() {
    ++ptr;
    return *this;
  }
  
  self operator++(int) {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++ptr;
    return copy;
  }
};

template <typename T, size_t size>
struct Array {
  using value_type = T;
  using iterator = ArrayIterator<T>;

  T arr[size];

  iterator begin() {
    return iterator(arr);
  }
  
  iterator end() {
    return iterator(arr + size);
  }
};

int main() {
  using array = Array<int, 5>;
  array arr{1, 3, 4, 22, 3};
  for (auto val : arr) {
    cout << val << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't get why it can't access because template instantiation happens at compile time.

```
template <typename T>
struct Rat {
  using value_type = typename T::value_type;
};

struct Cat: Rat<Cat> {
  using value_type = std::string;
};
```

Comment: @Vegeta like I said, because `Array::value_type` hasn’t been defined yet, because the contents of `Array` haven’t been defined yet, when `ArrayIterator` tries to access them. And that is exactly what the error message is telling you.